# Remove android setting screen from recent list

Tags: java, android, background, settings, android-recents

I am developing a kiosk mode app that requires me to remove any app in the background and recent list. This includes the settings page and any other system related screens. How do I do that if I don't have a rooted device?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks but if rooting is the only option then perhaps this cannot be done in a normal way.